# ctrl+c(copy text) not working in jquery modal dialog box

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using jquery modal dialog box in my application. it works fine in across the browsers.
but i am not able to use ctrl+c(copy text) basic browser keyboard functionality.
please tell me how i can make it working for me.

demo of problem can be seen on http://jsbin.com/anuso

Comment: I have the same problem. Any directions to dig in?